# htaccess redirect folder except 1 subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

On my, I want to redirect everything that comes **after** www.mysite.nl/news/ back to www.mysite.nl/news, except for www.mysite.nl/news/page (and everything that comes after /page)

How do I do such thing with .htaccess?

EDIT: I'm using these rules:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/page.*$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/.+ news/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run a rewrite rule for the subfolder you wish to exclude - /news/page - first.

Use `-` to mean "don't redirect" and `[L]` for "Last thing, stop now if you match".

Or, if you want it to run through WordPress, use `index.php`

Then redirect URLs that start /news/

This way, the excluded subfolder will not reach the redirect rule.

So:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/page.*$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/.+ news/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Use `.+` to mean one or more any-character instead of `.*` which means any or none any-character, to avoid redirecting news/ to news/.

Comment: Ehm... I don't want to redirect www.mysite.nl/news/page, thats the thing. Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: Sure, I should have said rewrite rule, not redirect, and I should have been clearer that the rule would be don't redirect. All there now with an untested example.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I first added the 4th and 5th rule of your code to the <ifModule mod_rewrite.c> that was allready there due to Wordpress. That didn't work. I then copied your code and pasted it as a stand alone piece and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Yeah, any previous rules would affect them. Glad it works for you.

Comment: If you're doing this within WordPress, you could instead use a plugin like Redirection.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a little over enthousiastic. The rewrite rules don't seem to work. At first I found out that /nieuws/page was not accesable. "Object not found! The requested url was not found on this server." Then I noticed that a lot of pages are not being redirected back to /nieuws (some do, but a lot don't).

Comment: I'll look into the plugin thing. I allready have a plugin for 301 redirections, but it doesnt allow me to redirect multiple urls (and exclude a certain subfolder).

Comment: Sorry, I had omitted the R=301 bit that would redirect and change the URL rather than simply redirect the script to another part. Now edited.

Comment: Edited again to send /news/page through to WordPress' index.php - the original version assumed something actually existed at /news/page within the filesystem.

Comment: The /news/page thing is fixed now. But still a lot of pages are not being redirected

Comment: Example url: http://www.alcadis.nl/nieuws/virtual-controller-biedt-uitkomst-voor-freedomlab-studies.htm

Comment: Sorry again, I made a typo :) My problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/page.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news
RewriteRule / http://mysite.nl/news [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect everything but the `/news` or `news/page` to the `/news` folder.

Comment: These rules keep redirecting /news in an endless loop

Comment: Yeah, although [L] should mean it's only done once, using a 301 redirect means a new request - so all the rules are processed again.

Comment: It shouldn't look though since it is being redirected to `/news` and `/news` is excluded from the redirect.

Comment: @Howlin, your `[OR]` is negating the exclusions - it is saying "if it's not /news/page or if it's not /news". As /news is not /news/page, it will not be excluded. Not sure whether you just need to take that out or put `[C]` in after the second Cond.